# Why is my secondary yAxis not matching to my xAxis in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am building a combination column/scatter chart using Highcharts. My xAxis data is a categorical set of countries, with two sets of numerical data on yAxis[0] and yAxis[1].

I am trying to essentially duplicate this HighCharts example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes/

Here is my version:

https://jsfiddle.net/MossTheTree/37r1w7f7/

With the xAxis:

```
xAxis: [{
    categories: ["People's Republic of China",
                'United States', 
                'India', 
                'Australia',
                'Indonesia',
                'Russian Federation',
                'South Africa',
                'Germany',
                'Poland',
                'Kazakhstan',
                'Rest of the world'],
    labels: {
        rotation: -45,
        style: {
            fontSize: '13px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    },
    crosshair: true
}],
```

and the yAxis:

```
yAxis: [{
    title: {
        text: 'Coal production (Megatonnes)'
    },
    labels: {
        format: '{value} Mt'
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 4000,
    tickInterval: 250
},
{
    labels: {
        format: '{value}%'
    },
    title: {
        text: '% of world total'
    },
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    opposite: true
}],
```

And the series:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Production',
    type: 'column',
    data: [3527, 813, 691, 509, 469, 349, 252, 185, 136, 107, 671],
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' Mt'
    }
},{
     name: 'Percentage of World Total',
     yAxis: 1,
     type: 'scatter',
    data: [45.8, 10.5, 9.0, 6.6, 6.1, 4.5, 3.3, 2.4, 1.8, 1.4, 8.6],
     tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    }      
}]
```

In general it's all displaying correctly, except the shared tooltip isn't working. **Somehow the data plotted to yAxis[1] is not being matched to the xAxis categorical data**, and are rather being matched to some integer x values.

I've checked and re-checked against the demo I'm trying to replicate but can't see any obvious errors. What is wrong with my syntax that could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display scatter points inside shared tooltip, instead of using scatter, you can use line type series and disable line, by setting `lineWidth` and `lineWidthPlus` on hover with 0 value.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.line.lineWidth
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.marker.states.hover.lineWidthPlus

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/epwxacoa/